# Insert XML node value as attribute with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

I have a XML document with the following structure:

```sql
DECLARE @XMLDocument XML = '
<Root>
    <MainNode>
        <Key>10</Key>
        <Info></Info>
    </MainNode>
    <MainNode>
        <Key>13</Key>
        <Info>15</Info>
        <Info>18</Info>
    </MainNode>
</Root>';
```

I want to modify the structure of the XML by getting rid of the Key node in every Main Node, inserting the information they contain as an atribute, so that the end result would look like this.

```xml
<Root>
    <MainNode Key="10">
        <Info></Info>
    </MainNode>
    <MainNode Key="13">
        <Info>15</Info>
        <Info>18</Info>
    </MainNode>
</Root>
```

I have tried different approaches but none has worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: xml modification is usually painful in sql server, because you cannot update more than one place easily. Is it feasable to shred xml back to regular data and then collect it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [siggemannen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13061224/siggemannen) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77612891/insert-xml-node-value-as-attribute-with-sql-server/77613172#comment136827495_77612891), this might be easier by consuming the XML and creating new XML from that. You can then easily move the key from a node to an attribute by aliasing it as `[@Key]`:

```sql
DECLARE @XMLDocument XML = '
<Root>
    <MainNode>
        <Key>10</Key>
        <Info></Info>
    </MainNode>
    <MainNode>
        <Key>13</Key>
        <Info>15</Info>
        <Info>18</Info>
    </MainNode>
</Root>';

SELECT R.MN.value('(Key/text())[1]','int') AS [@Key],
       (SELECT ISNULL(MN.I.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(10)'),'') AS Info --As you want a blank row we need to use a string, as '' would be 0 as a int.
        FROM  R.MN.nodes('Info') MN(I)
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
FROM @XMLDocument.nodes('/Root/MainNode')R(MN)
FOR XML PATH('MainNode'),ROOT('Root');
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, it's easier to just rebuild the XML.

A slightly shorter syntax than the other answer, and the benefit is that you don't need to rebuild everything.

Just select out everything else apart from `<Key>` using `.query` and add it as an unnamed column

```sql
DECLARE @XMLDocument XML = '
<Root>
    <MainNode>
        <Key>10</Key>
        <Info></Info>
    </MainNode>
    <MainNode>
        <Key>13</Key>
        <Info>15</Info>
        <Info>18</Info>
    </MainNode>
</Root>';

SELECT
  R.MN.value('(Key/text())[1]','int') AS [@Key],
  R.MN.query('*[local-name() != "key"]')
FROM @XMLDocument.nodes('/Root/MainNode')R(MN)
FOR XML PATH('MainNode'), ROOT('Root'), TYPE;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/8BGDW6QQ)

Comment: `R.MN.query('*[local-name() != "key"]')`is a nice trick!

Comment: Thank you very much Charlieface, it worked as intended!

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use SQL Server native XQuery functionality via FLWOR expression.

It allows to compose a desired output XML "visually".

Check it out below.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @XMLDocument XML = 
N'<Root>
    <MainNode>
        <Key>10</Key>
        <Info></Info>
    </MainNode>
    <MainNode>
        <Key>13</Key>
        <Info>15</Info>
        <Info>18</Info>
    </MainNode>
</Root>';

SELECT @XMLDocument.query('<Root>
    {
        for $x in /Root/MainNode
        return <MainNode Key="{$x/Key}">
            {$x/*[not(local-name()="Key")]}
            </MainNode>
    }
</Root>');
```

**Output**

```
<Root>
  <MainNode Key="10">
    <Info />
  </MainNode>
  <MainNode Key="13">
    <Info>15</Info>
    <Info>18</Info>
  </MainNode>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yitzhak, this solution worked as well :)